# Change groovy compiler to specific version in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy, setup-project

Is there a way to change my groovy compiler version in Eclipse to a specific one? [image]

Like for example above, I have those versions I could choose from but the version I need (2.4.3) is not in the list. I want to use groovy 2.4.3, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can install additional versions of the Groovy Compiler in Eclipse via Help -> Install new Software... -> Select your groovy eclipse update site and open "Groovy Compilers (Optional). It will appear in the list after installation.

If you cannot see the 2.4 compiler, you might need to add a recent Release or Snapshot URL listed here: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki

The current version in the snapshot builds of the 2.4 branch is 2.4.12, which should be close enough.

The plugin uses a patched version of the Groovy Compiler. So you would need to build your own version of the plugin to integrate your own groovy version.